# Possible to use IF in a query?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, grafana

I'm using Grafana to plot data from a MySQL datasource. Is it possible to, in a panel's query editor, use an IF ... THEN ... type statement. I would like to create a variable that I could put in the IF. I want the variable to be a condition, not necessarily to be used directly in the query.

For example:

```
//IN THE DATA SOURCE:

CREATE TABLE Example (Id INT, ANIMALS VARCHAR(15));
INSERT INTO Example VALUES (1,'Dog'), (2,'Fish'), (3,'Cat'), (4,'Lizard')
```

For a variable Test with values "Mammal',"Reptile", "Other":

```
//WHAT I'D LIKE IN GRAFANA QUERY EDITOR:

IF($Test = "Mammal") THEN
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE Id = 1 OR Id =3;
ELSE
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE Id = 2 OR Id =4;
END IF;
```

Is this kind of condition based query even possible? If so, what is the proper syntax to get it to work? Is there any way I can use Grafana variables to have a similar effect?

Comment: Why you need this kind of business logic in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use query. Query starts with SELECT keyword. Don't use any IF ELSE conditions before query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Example 
WHERE 
  Data IN ( ${variable:csv} )
```

This WHERE condition syntax will work with single value, multi value Grafana dashboard variables and also with `All` value (no custom All value, but `blank=auto`). Of course this condition is mainly for INT column types. STRING types may need different one (e.g. with LIKE and regexp matching).

Code all your logic (dependency on the dashboard variable) in the WHERE section. Use query inspector to see SQL which is generated and tweak it to correct SQL syntax.

Comment: What is the ${idvariable:csv} part?

Comment: @always_confused https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/  you have mentioned that you want to use variable

Comment: Works fine with just Data IN ($variable)  is there a reason for specifying csv format?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an `if`, you can use `or`. It's really useful for conditionally checking variables:

```
select * from Example
where (Id in (1,3) or '$Test' != 'Mammal')
and (Id in (2,4) or '$Test' == 'Mammal')
```